# For Each In: Is it possible to run through a single-column range and paste multiple columns, starting with that first FOR cell?

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, montecarlo

I've been having trouble trying to optimize a certain part of my code. I am performing a Monte Carlo simulation and I want to copy the values of a range a repeated number of times. To do this, I've used a For Each In structure. Below is a minimal example.

```
sub example()
Dim live As Excel.Range 'the range to be copied in each For Each In
Dim acell as Excel.Range 'For range
Set live = Range("C5:P5")

For Each acell in Range("B9:B90")
acell.value=live.value
Next acell

End Sub
```

The problem is that `live` spans multiple columns, while `acell` is just one cell; what ends up happening is just the first column is copied, the rest are blank. I have also used `For Each acell in XYZ.rows` where `XYZ` is a previously defined range of multiple columns and rows. However, this is considerably slower.

Is it possible to run through a single-column range and paste multiple columns, starting with that first cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there; you're just missing a tiny change in your code. You have to `Resize` the target range. Instead of

```
bcell.value=live.value ' bcell (presumably a typo) is only 1 column wide
```

use

```
acell.Resize(1, live.Columns.Count).Value = live.Value
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it with .Columns("A:N") but your suggestion is a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Sub example()
Dim live As Excel.Range 'the range to be copied in each For Each In
Dim acell As Excel.Range 'For range
Set live = Range("C5:P5")

live.Copy
Range("B9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , , True

End Sub
```

Comment: But this copies to one row only?... Also, this I learned the hard way: `Copy`-`PasteSpecial` uses the clipboard, and this should be avoided if at all possible! Other programs may read from / write to the clipboard while your code is running, with unpredictable results at both ends.

Comment: No, this copies the entire 1-row range to a 1-column range the same way the UI's Paste Special | Values | Transpose would. Fair enough point on use of the clipboard though!

Comment: Ok, sure, to one *column* only... but that's not what the OP asks?!

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to read `C5:P5` in as an array:

```
Sub CopyLoop()
    Dim copyRng(), targetRng As Range, cl As Range

    copyRng = Range("C5:P5") 'Read in as array
    Set targetRng = Range("B9:B90")

    For Each cl In targetRng
        Range("B" & cl.Row & ":O" & cl.Row) = copyRng
    Next cl
End Sub
```